# Error while removing the new kernel 2.6.37

Tags: kernel, software-center

I tried to install the new kernel but something went wrong and I'm trying to remove it now.
The error massege is:

```
mhd@Tarek-Laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-2.6.37-020637-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 111MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 188780 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-2.6.37-020637-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.37-020637-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.37-020637-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.37-020637-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.37-020637-generic
/etc/default/grub: 33: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.37-020637-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.37-020637-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-2.6.37-020637-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The previous unsloved error is on this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/aptdaemon/+bug/700654).

This is my grub configuration file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1024x768-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap" video=uvesafb:mode_option=>>1024x768-24<<,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" vga=792 splash"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768-24

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2):

I found the fix for this bug by this codes:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.37-020637-generic.postrm
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.37-020637-generic.list

sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I ran `sudo apt-get update` twice.

Then I run synaptic and manually remove the package and my system is clean again.

Many thanks to this [blog](http://allforlinux.com/2010/07/solving-e-sub-process-usrbindpkg-returned-an-error-code1/).

Comment: You may need to run `sudo update-grub` again too after the kernel is removed from `/boot`

Comment: @Tarek. Please help. I have the same problem and I did what you mentioned but I still get: ```Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic
 linux-image-5.4.0-51-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```

Answer (score 0):

This is odd, it looks as if the kernel upgrade has somehow changed the grub configuration file. Can you post the grub configuration file in your question above so we can have a look at it?

This is what mine looks like, and if you want you can replace yours with this:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```