# partial upgrade

Tags: package-management, updates, 13.10

I didn't connect to the internet for about a week, then when I got connected to the internet I tried to update the system. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. It said it needs partial upgrade. When I click partial upgrade, it says that the system is up-to-date and cancels.
When I click *Continue*, it says `software index is broken`. It is impossible to install or remove any software. Please use the Synaptic package manager or run `sudo apt-get install -f` in the terminal to fix the issue. At first I did that.

that's the results in the terminal:

```
The following packages will be removed:
  linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
17 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 136 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? "
i click y but it doesn't work .that's the outcome ...
"(Reading database ... 401370 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following commands in terminal,

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If you still getting errors, try to update your kernel by running the below command.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Comment: still errors .i can't post the outcome here .the site says it's too long .

Comment: Did it shows the error while running sudo apt-get install linux-generic.copy and paste the error in pastebin.com and post the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Us8JEaTA

Comment: what was the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: please reply fast.

Comment: run this command to remove old kernals `sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')` after that the error doesn't shown up.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/s6j9tJk2

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T8PzquWc

Comment: are you sure about this ? i'm rather worried .

Comment: see this page http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CMrk43g2

Comment: see this page http://askubuntu.com/questions/20824/error-while-removing-the-new-kernel-2-6-37

Comment: i'm not really good with terminal ,Avinash .

Comment: i think it's the same problem as mine .

Comment: i tried to replace the name of his kernil with mine but it didn't work .

Comment: i've been having this problem for a few weeks now and you really helped me .thanks a lot .

Comment: how can i accept it ?

Comment: select the tick mark below the down-arrow.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Hi could you please help, I have the same issue with my ubuntu 20.04. I recently upgraded from 18.04, it was working fine then. I have been stuck on it for a long time, please help. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284736/software-index-is-broken?noredirect=1#comment2180638_1284736)